# How can I pass the values of string variables defined in VB.net code into a CefSharp browser and call them by their name using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, cefsharp

First time user of CefSharp. I'm trying to use it with vb.net to automate some tasks in a website.

I created a ChromiumWebBrowser and pointed it to a website with 2 input fields Username and Password.
I managed to use javascript for filling the 2 input fileds with the 2 corresponding strings as follows:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = 'MyUsername';
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = 'MyPassword';
```

and IT WORKS. I'm seeing the 2 fileds filled with the 2 strings. (The fileds have no Id. That's why the getElementsByTagName)

Now, I want, instead of the actual strings inside the javascript code, to pass the strings from variables inside my VB.net code. Something like:

VB.net code

```
Dim USER as String = 'MyUsername'
Dim PASS as String = 'MyPassword'
```

and the previous JS code to something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = USER;
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = PASS;
```

but obviously not that!

I found some posts about putting in my VB code something like this

```
browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("boundAsync", New BoundObject())
```

and a Public Class BoundObject

and pass it to JS code like

```
await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("boundAsync", "bound");
```

but I'm confused on how to do it with the 2 strings I mentioned before.
**How can I register the USER and PASS variables in VB.net and then call their values in JS to fill the input fields?**

TIA

Comment: Registering an object isn't necessary just build your string in VB.Net before executing your javascript. Simple string concatination will work, or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1 or the newer syntax using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: Can you please clarify what to write after the = (equal sign) in the following JS line?  document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = USER;

Comment: It's just adding multiple string together. A super simple example at https://gist.github.com/amaitland/4c52b7001c22506cb7ca9a4e649956b5#file-script-cs I don't write VB.Net so I cannot write you an exact example.

Comment: Hmm. But then my mock-up example in my original post should work as it is. document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = USER;
Just putting the name of the variable defined in my vb.net code. Unfortunately it doesn't. And if I put it inside single quotes (like your example) it just fill the input field with the word USER (the name of the variable) and not MyUsername which is its value.

Comment: No You are right. I got it finally! It seems to be a single/double quotes issue. Thank you for now! (and expect more questions from this newbie later!)

Comment: You can post your own answer with an example of VB code that might help others :+1:

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was doing that, just now!

in VB.net code

```
Dim USER as String = 'MyUsername'
```

and in JS code

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = '" + USER + "';
```

the trick is in the quotes. Instead of writing = USER
you put it like this `'" + USER + "'`

Comment: Accept you answer as a correct answer. ... It seems that the VB variables are exposed to your JavaScript space. How about the special variable like "document", what will happen if you declare such variable in your VB?

Comment: Yes the VB variables are exposed to the JS.
About special variables I just tested the following:

I put the "document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value" part as a VB variable (as String) and it worked!